# How to pass a subquery as a parameter to a MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, subquery, procedure

Is there a way I could pass a whole subquery as a parameter to my MySQL function and execute it under a condition? Something (but less faulty) like this..

```
delimiter //
create procedure myFunction (mySubquery)
begin
    if (true) then
        execute mySubquery;
    end if;
    /*rest of the action*/
end //
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the query as a good ol'string (a.k.a. `VARCHAR`) and [prepare a statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html) from it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc (param VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SET @query = param;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    SET @query = NULL;        
END;

-- later on...
CALL proc('SELECT 1');
```

*N.B. the ugly `SET @query = param;` workaround is required because "A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to (...) function parameters". (i.e. `PREPARE stmt FROM param;` is not allowed). Yuck.*

You should add an [error handler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) to such a procedure, because a broken query may (will eventually, as per Moore's law ;) be provided as a parameter. Your procedure should be prepared to handle this case gracefully.

Comment: thanks for updating your first reply - without-the-workaround version left me puzzled for a moment :D

Comment: @JaakKütt Also, beware, such a procedure may allow a lot of unwanted stuff. Make sure you only allow trusted people to run it. Perhaps even declare it with the [`SQL SECURITY INVOKER` property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-security.html).

Comment: thanks for the advice... atm I'm only going to use it for testing :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists myFunction;
create procedure myFunction (mySubquery varchar(500))
begin
    if (true) then
        SET @mySubquery = mySubquery;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @mySubquery;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    end if;
/*rest of the action*/
end //
delimiter ;
```